# Could you plz tell the file uploading using jquery with easiest way?

Tags: php, html, superglobals

I want to use the easiest method for uploading file through jquery ajax.

My code is:

```
<body>
   <form action="?" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="myfile" /><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   <div>
      <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         //move_uploaded_files()...
      }
      ?>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php: _"An associative array of items uploaded to the current script **via the HTTP POST method**. The structure of this array is outlined in the **POST method uploads** section."_ (bold highlighting by me) - based on this, could you really expect it to work for a _different_ method than POST ...?

Answer (score 3):

When you use a form on a webpage to send data to a server, you have a choice between using the `GET` or `POST` methods. These methods determine how the data is sent to the server.

When you set the form method to `GET`, the data you fill in the form fields, including the file you select, gets added to the web address in a way. You might have noticed that the URL in the browser changes when you submit the form. However, this approach has some limitations. It's not great for sending big chunks of data like files, and there's a maximum limit to how much data you can send this way.

On the other hand, when you use the `POST` method, the data you enter into the form is sent in a different way, sort of like a hidden package in the background. It's more suitable for larger amounts of data, which includes files. This is why your file upload works when you change the form method to `POST`. The server knows how to handle this type of data and stores it properly.

In your specific situation, when you change the form method to `GET`, the `$_FILES` array doesn't work as expected because it's meant to deal with data sent using the `POST` method. It's kind of like trying to fit a round peg in a square hole – the `GET` method isn't designed to handle file uploads the way `POST` does.

If you really need to use the `GET` method and still want to upload files, it's a bit tricky. You might have to get creative and encode the file data in a way that can be added to the URL, but that's not the best way to handle files due to various issues.

Generally, for file uploads, it's much better to use the `POST` method. It ensures that your file gets safely to the server and avoids the complications of trying to fit a big thing like a file into a small space like a URL. If you're set on using `GET`, you might need to think about different ways to achieve your goal, like temporarily storing the files on the server and passing references to those files through the URL.

Answer (score 0):

That's because GET requests don't have a body, and that's where files would go

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34870332)

Comment: @Korashen While the answer lacks supporting information, it is exactly the answer to the question.